# page curl effect using pdf file

Tags: flutter

I have a PDF file and I would like to reproduce a page curl effect like in this package page:

https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/page_turn

I tried using this [page_turn](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/page_turn) plugin and it takes list of widgets that will display in order. I tried using [native_pdf_renderer](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/native_pdf_renderer) plugin to render the pdf and display on each page, but when I do this, the pages are blank. but if I remove from the PageTurn widget, it works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_pdf_renderer/native_pdf_renderer.dart';
import 'package:page_turn/page_turn.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = GlobalKey<PageTurnState>();

  Future<PdfPageImage> getPageImage() async {
    final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/pdfs/222.pdf');
    final page = await document.getPage(6);
    final pageImage = await page.render(
      width: page.width,
      height: page.height,
      format: PdfPageFormat.JPEG,
    );
    await page.close();
    return pageImage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<PdfPageImage>(
        future: getPageImage(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          // This works:
          // return Image(
          //   image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
          // );
          //This makes all my pages blank
          return PageTurn(
            key: _controller,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(
                image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
              ),
              Image(
                image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
              ),
              Image(
                image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after reading the lib code i see there is widget to show image pre-renderd
you should use PageTurnImage instead Image like this

```
 PageTurn(
        key: _controller,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        children: <Widget>[
          PageTurnImage(
            image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
          ),
          PageTurnImage(
            image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
          ),
          PageTurnImage(
            image: MemoryImage(snapshot.data.bytes),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

try it and give me a feedback and up vote if it work

Comment: it didn't work. I can't import and use `PageTurnImage` from the package. I tried to copy the source code of the package and pasting in my lib folder and I got that `amount != null` is not true. I also tried to specifying an `AnimationController(value: 100, vsync: this)` but i got a blank page again. I guess that maybe the `PageTurnImage` is not ready yet

Comment: i did pull request to fix this issue I think in the next version will be fixed , in the current time fork the lib and edit the PageTurnImage to fix it

Comment: How can I fix the `PageTurnImage`?